Is “gcc” on macOS actually “clang”?
Does macOS have clang and gcc at the same time, but they are actually the same thing?
When I ran the following command：
gcc -v

I discovered that "gcc" is actually "clang", as shown in the screenshot here：
enter image description here
I then found two files on my MacBook: /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/clang. They appear to be separate files rather than symbolic links, but I suspect they have the same content, as shown in the screenshot here:
enter image description here

It seems like the file /usr/bin/clang was copied and then renamed to gcc.

What's going on here?

Its the same content in both files. And both are clang.

Typing "gcc --version" outputs clang version instead on mac, Which version of gcc is installed on Mac (Yosemite)

Actually, these two files (and others as well) are hard links.  You can see this with ls -li which shows the inode number:
--> ls -li /usr/bin/cc /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/clang
1152921500312525479 -rwxr-xr-x  77 root  wheel  119008 Aug  4 22:31 /usr/bin/cc
1152921500312525479 -rwxr-xr-x  77 root  wheel  119008 Aug  4 22:31 /usr/bin/clang
1152921500312525479 -rwxr-xr-x  77 root  wheel  119008 Aug  4 22:31 /usr/bin/gcc

On my machine there are a total of 77 links to that executable -- not sure where all the others are.

It's basically all the programming stuff in /usr/bin (try find /usr/bin -inum 1152921500312525479). It appears to be just a shim to forward to xcrun to get the correct version, after mapping alternate compiler names to clang or clang++ as appropriate.
